# Error trying to set up Spark REST example

Tags: java, rest, spark-java

I am trying to set up the simple Spark REST example as described here:
http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html

When I browse to :
http://localhost:4567/hello

I get this error:

```
[qtp346024113-15] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - //localhost:4567/hello
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:       javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getHeaders(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Collection;
at spark.utils.GzipUtils.checkAndWrap(GzipUtils.java:64)
at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:251)
at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks a problem with the classpath, but I don't know what dependencies are missing.

The dependencies in my pom.xml for Spark are as follows:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
    </dependency>


  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.3.v20150827</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
   <artifactId>websocket-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>9.3.3.v20150827</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
package com.hello.rest.api;

 import static spark.Spark.*;

public class RestAPI {

public RestAPI() {

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Processing hello");
    get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
}


}
```

Comment: You're declaring those dependencies on your POM? Also, show your code. It's not clear to me what is the "simple Spark REST example" you mentioned.

Comment: What about your POM? Are you defining all those dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error implies, the method *getHeaders* doesn't exist in the *HttpServletResponse* class that is called.

This method does exist since Servlet 3.0 .

Make sure that your classpath doesn't contain older versions of Servlet API, which includes the class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse .

Also, maybe one of your dependencies contain an older version of it.

Comment: Do you know how to exclude the older version of the servlet api in `build.gradle` ? I have tried `exclude` and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Ye Lin Aung : No sorry, I don't know much about gradle .

Comment: Using maven you can find out if a dependency is using an old api version with 

`mvn dependency:tree`

and searching for a line with `javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:X.Y`.